# Find the range and kernel of a matrix times itself transposed, using SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I do have the matrix $A=U\Sigma V^T$ with the SVD
$$ U = \frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1&-2\\ 1&2&2\\ 2&-2&1\end{bmatrix}$$ $$ \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 3&0\\0&0.3\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$V=\begin{bmatrix} 0.8&0.6\\-0.6&0.8 \end{bmatrix}$$
Now I would like to calculate the $\ker(AA^\top)$ & $\mathrm{range}(AA^\top)$.

Due to the SVD I know $AA^\top$ does only have $2$ eigenvalues, which results in $\mathrm{rank}(AA^\top)=2$.

With the SVD I know that it should be $\mathrm{range}(A)= \mathrm{Span}\{u_1, u_2\}$ & $\ker(A)=\mathrm{Span}\{0\}$. (as there is no $v_3$. Right?)

How can I proceed from here? Can I use properties of the SVD to get the kernel and range of $AA^\top$ quickly without calculating $A$?

Comment: How do you multiply the $3\times 3$ matrix $U$ from the right with the $2\times 3$ matrix $\Sigma$ ?

Comment: You are right. The Matrix was tansposed. I fixed the matrix in the question

Comment: You want ker and range of $AA^\top$ or of $A$ ?

Comment: Since $U,V$ are both unitary (orthogonal) we have $AA^\top=U(\Sigma\Sigma^\top)U^\top$. Therefore, up to the transformation by $U$ the kernel and the range of $AA^\top$ can be obtained from the kernel and range of $\Sigma\Sigma^\top$ which equals $\operatorname{diag}(9,0.09,0)$.